# Why do spiders have a leaf at the bottom of a piece of web?

Tags: evolution

I've lately seen a lot of instances where a leaf is dangling from a piece of web coming down off a tree. What purpose/s does this serve for the spider? Is it some sort of mechanism for the spider to determine the wind / disturbances in that region?

I've seen a [suggestion](http://calamvalecreek.awardspace.com/web-leaf.html) that it's to help act as a plumb during web construction to keep part of it tight, but do we actually know for sure?

Here's a national geographic image showing what I mean:
[image] 
http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/ngm/photo-contest/2012/entries/177963/view/

Comment: I would think that these leave simply got caught by the net.

Comment: It's attached to a single piece of thread, dangling about 5ft from the ground.

Comment: Could the spider have used the leaf as support for the web while it was still attached the tree, then the leaf fell off the tree and still hung on the web?

Comment: @user137 interesting idea, and would explain why I only see it in autumn. It wouldn't have to necessarily be part of the web for this to be viable.

Comment: I've also come to reason that spiders use web to move from leaf to leaf, so it may just be a leaf that's had web shot onto it by the spider and was attached to a more permanent part of the tree.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, it has a practical effect. Spiders hunt for small insect and don't like when bigger animals damage their webs. So that they make the web visible for mammals, but in the way which doesn't prevent the prey from being caught.

I don't have reference for this, my colleague (entomologist) told me so.

Comment: I like this thought.  It's like the owl decals we put on windows to keep the birds from banging their heads on the glass.  I, for one, won't walk into a web I know is there.

Comment: It would be good to have a reference for this claim or to clarify that this is just a guess.